# Need hint on induction proof for summation

Tags: proof-verification, summation, notation, induction, proof-explanation

I have a homework problem to prove the following via induction:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^22^{n-i} = 2^{n+3}-2^{n+1}-n^2-4n -6$$
The base case is true.  I generated the below using $s_k+a_{k+1}=s_{k+1}$:
$$ 2^{k+3}-2^{k+1}-k^2-4k-6+(k+1)^22^{n-(k+1)}=2^{k+4}-2^{k+2}-(k+1)^2-4(k+1)-6 $$
which I've simplified down to:

$$ (k+1)^22^{n-(k+1)}=-2k-5 $$
However, I have no idea what to do with $n$ and I haven't been able to figure out what to Google to get a hint.  So my questions are:

1. What do you call it when you have $n$ on the left side of summation notation like this (i.e. what search terms might help)?
2. Am I using the correct process, or am I way off track? (And/or have I made any errors in my simplification?)
3. What do I do with $n$?  I tried making $n=k+1$, which seemed logical to me, but it doesn't work out.

Thanks for any suggestions/hints you have!

Comment: If $n = 1$ your formula reads $1 = 16 - 4 - 1 - 6$.

Comment: Let me put it a different way. If $n=1$ your formula reads $1 = 5$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Good catch, I had a typo in the original equation; fixed it.  However, my work so far remains the same.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you have already performed the base case.

Assume this holds for $k \in \mathbb{N}.$ We see that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^2 2^{k+1 - i}
= 2\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} i^2 2^{k-i}$$
$$=2\left((k+1)^2 2^{-1} + \sum_{i=1}^{k} i^2 2^{k-i}\right),$$
which by our inductive hypothesis
$$=2\left((k+1)^2 2^{-1} + 2^{k+3} - 2^{k+1} - k^2 - 4k - 6\right)$$
$$=(k+1)^2 + 2^{(k+1)+3} - 2^{(k+1)+1} - 2k^2 - 8k - 12$$
$$=k^2 + 2k + 1 + 2^{(k+1)+3} - 2^{(k+1)+1} - 2k^2 - 8k - 12$$
$$=2^{(k+1)+3} - 2^{(k+1)+1} - k^2 - 6k - 11.$$

Hence, it suffices to show that

$$-k^2 - 6k - 11 = -(k+1)^2 - 4(k+1) - 6.$$

We see that
$$-(k+1)^2 - 4(k+1) - 6 = -(k^2 + 2k + 1) - 4k -4 - 6  = -k^2 - 2k - 1 -4k -4 -6$$
$$=-k^2 - 6k - 11,$$

And thus our above statement holds for $k+1.$ Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, our statement holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to work through this, and really appreciate your help.